# How to make nullable column in table using ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
[Table("tblCources")]

public class Cource : EntityBase
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

I have mapped enire class having multiple property with a table using data annotation (asp.net entity framework ORM).

Here is my question,
How can i make desc column nullable in "tblCources" table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` types **are** nullable, so EF should pick that up (assuming Code First).

For types other than `string`, for example `int` or `Guid`, just make those nullable by adding a `?` on the end of the type (e.g. `int?` or `Guid?`). That way they'll become nullable in your generated database.